# Complex numbers in Swift?

Tags: complex-numbers, swift

Does Apple's Swift language support complex numbers out of the box?

I couldn't find any mention in the docs any equivalent for C++ `std::complex` nor could I find one when playing with it.

Comment: can you bridge in complex.h?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wrote the following:

https://github.com/dankogai/swift-complex

Just add complex.swift to your project and you can go like:

```
let z = 1-1.i
```

It has all functions and operators that  of C++11 covers.

Unlike C++11 complex.swift is not generic -- z.real and z.imag are always Double.

But the necessity for complex integer is very moot and IMHO it should be treated in different type ([GaussianInteger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), maybe).

Comment: Yes, very elegant syntax. I like the "1.i". However, for most realistic application, they may be used in a more computational intensive context. So performance may be a great concern.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's [Swift Numerics](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics) package supports complex numbers. It was first released on November 7, 2019. The package became stable with a [1.0.0 release](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics/releases/tag/1.0.0) on August 31, 2021.

Here are some examples from the [initial release announcement](https://www.swift.org/blog/numerics/) :

```swift
import Complex

let z: Complex<Double> = 2 + 3 * .i
print(z.real)      // 2.0
print(z.imaginary) // 3.0

let w = Complex<Double>(1, -2) // (1.0, -2.0)

let u: Complex<Double> = .i * .i // (-1.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

No. You may import the `Accelerate` module via `import Accelerate` and use the `DSPComplex` type. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html) for more detail.

Comment: My experience with Accelerate is limited to a few line of testing and watching WWDC video. I took a dive to try to convert and i to a -i as a warm up and I find thats quite lot of boilerplate code working with this in Swift, such as code that convert/bridge from one "type" to another, in order to make it interoperate with C. Most of the APIs really work with vector. So if you don't have a vectorized problem at hand, I wonder if the overhead will be worth the trouble and dankogai's neat struct and integer extension could even be more performant.

Comment: typo: "integer extension" is "Double extension"